# WordPress wpdb->get_results not showing the result

Tags: php, wordpress

sorry for the dump question. I was a vb programmer 8 years ago. I m trying to do some WP programming. As I have also less knowledge in PHP I got struct with silly mistake. What I need to pass url to another function. I get no message shown when I echo =$url->url;

```
 global $wpdb;   
 $urls=$wpdb->get_results("select url from sbp_urls");
  $wpdb->num_rows; //( its okay 171 records there) 

  foreach($urls as $url){

         $response=$url->url;
     }

 echo $response;

 nothing is shown . Where is my mistake to get url with the code $url->url; ?
```

Comment: It might be showing one result.Is it?

Comment: Thanks a lot .nothing is shown actually . But when try like this 
foreach($urls as $url){

         $response=$url;
     }

 echo $response;

I get the following error message 
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: What does it give if you try like `  foreach($urls as $url){
         $response=$url->url; echo $response;
     }`?

Comment: Can you add `print_r($urls);` before `foreach` statement and let me know the output?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks a lot. Actually the last row ($url->url) has no value. that is why it was showing nothing.

Thanks a lot.